# Access Stripe Payment Element's loading state

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, stripe-payments

In my Reactjs app, I'm using the payment intent API from stripe to handle payments. I use the embeddable Payment Element `<PaymentElement />` from `@stripe/react-stripe-js` to render the UI but the problem is that it takes a couple of seconds before the Payment Element is fully loaded in the UI.

Is there any way I can access its loading state and show a loading spinner while it's being loaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stripe just added a new `loader` option to their PaymentElement product documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create#stripe_elements-options-loader). It allows you to have a skeleton render first while the UI is loading which should solve the problem you were going for.

Alternatively, you can listen to their `ready` event documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_ready) so that you show a loading animation until the event is fired.

While this is for their vanilla JS integration, you can use those with their React library since you control which option to pass on the PaymentElement on initialization.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I managed to add the `loader: "always"` to the `<Elements />` component's `options` and it works perfectly.

Comment: I found `loader:always` was insufficient when using the @stripe/stripe-js/pure, the event way worked great in this case.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone not content with simply using their loader, you can listen to the `ready` event ([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_ready)).

To do this, you have to get the element first, which is a step that confused me. You should have the `elements` reference from the `useElements` hook. In `useEffect` you can try to do `elements.getElement('paymentMethod')` but you will get an error saying:

> A valid Element name must be provided. Valid Elements are:   card,
> cardNumber, cardExpiry, cardCvc, postalCode, paymentRequestButton,
> iban, idealBank, p24Bank, auBankAccount, fpxBank, affirmMessage,
> afterpayClearpayMessage; you passed: paymentElement.

However, the correct thing to get is `payment` despite not being in that list:

```
const element = elements.getElement('payment')
element.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("READY")
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this and explaining how to implement in the react code!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Yeats on ready solved this for me - great answer.

I want to add for anyone looking at this solution that you should not hide your  until the on ready state returns. I mistakenly used a useState variable to show a loader until PaymentElement was ready, but realised that only the loader component needed to be toggled by state and that the PaymentElement should be rendered always. My first try I hid the PaymentElement from render using my loading state var like this:

***Don't do this!***

```
{isStripLoading ? (
  <MyLoaderComponent />
) : (
  <PaymentElement />
)}
```

So, assuming you have a state variable isStripeLoading default to true and you have useEffect on ready event setIsStripeLoading(false) then wrap only you loader spinner component in the isStripeLoading state variable and NOT the PaymentElement component.

Example

```
const stripe = useStripe()
const elements = useElements()
const [isStripeLoading, setIsStripeLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
    if (elements) {
      const element = elements.getElement('payment')
      element.on('ready', () => {
      setIsStripeLoading(false)
    })
  }
}, [elements])

return (
  <form id='payment-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    {isStripeLoading && <MyLoaderComponent />}
    <PaymentElement id='payment-element'/>
    <button id='submit' disabled={!stripe || !elements}>Pay</button>
  </form>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `onReady` attribute of the [`PaymentElement`](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react?#element-components).

picking up @j4jefferson's example:

```
const stripe = useStripe()
const elements = useElements()
const [isStripeLoading, setIsStripeLoading] = useState(true)

return (
  <form id='payment-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    {isStripeLoading && <MyLoaderComponent />}
    <PaymentElement id='payment-element' onReady={() => setIsStripeLoading(false)}/>
    <button id='submit' disabled={!stripe || !elements || isStripeLoading}>Pay</button>
  </form>
)
```

I am also using isStripeLoading to disable the button while the elements are still loading.